# Display list on a screen with three options

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture

I am working with a database containing people, each having an `isRetired` parameter.

By default, I retrieve non-retired people, but I need to implement functionality on the screen to display people in three ways:

- Active (non-retired people only),
- Retired (retired people only), and
- All (both retired and non-retired people).

How can I achieve this functionality in my application?

There is the problem, that i can retrieve data only by
retired false or true. I thought by adding new parameter "ShowAll"
and add if statement to service method(like is ShowAll=true then
query without retired), but it seems confusing for me as when someone
will debugging he could see like wow: ShowAll is true but Retired is
false or true. What is going on and what data should be received?
Does C# have any feature for this?

Here is my DTO I`m working with

```
public class PeopleDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Retired { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<PaginatedResult<People>> GetAll([FromQuery] PeopleDto peopleDto) => Ok(_peopleService.GetAll(peopleDto));
```

Here is my Service method

```
public PaginatedResult<People> GetAll(PeopleDto peopleDto)
    {

        var peopleList = _dbContext.People
            .Where(people => String.IsNullOrEmpty(peopleDto.Name)
                                    || people.Name.Contains(peopleDto.Name))
            .IsRetired(peopleDto.Retired)
            .OrderBy(people => people.Id)
            .ToList();

        int totalItems = _dbContext.People
            .IsRetired(peopleDto.Retired)
            .Count(people => String.IsNullOrEmpty(peopleDto.Name)
                                    || people.Name.Contains(peopleDto.Name));
        
        var paginatedPeople = new PaginatedResult<People>
        {
            Items = peopleList,
            TotalCount = totalItems,
        };

        return paginatedPeople;
    }

public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> IsRetired<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, bool isRetired) where T : People =>
        query.Where(people => people.Retired == isRetired);
}
```

Comment: You can write your ShowAll in a separate method and apply `.IsRetired` on it when calling from `GetAll`

Comment: BTW, your naming is confusing. Why is `GetAll` returning people filtered by name and active status? Isn't it supposed, by name, to get them all?

Comment: @Cid In my application, I default to displaying only active individuals. When sending a request, there's an option not to assign a name or specify the IsRetired status. In this scenario, since the boolean defaults to false if no data is assigned, I face a challenge. I want to handle the IsRetired status differently, akin to Java's ability to wrap a boolean and have it represent null (neither true nor false).

Comment: then use a nullable boolean : `bool?`. You don't have to change your data model, only the DTO. And then, in your extension method, you can do `.Where(people => (isRetired ?? people.Retired) == people.Retired);`